# ExtJS Grid will not sort

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a grid in ExtJS 3.4 but it will not sort.  I am getting this error in firebug when clicking on a column header:

invalid Array.prototype.sort argument

Line 48523

How do I fix it?

Here is the store, column, and grid definition:

```
function AircraftFeesStore() {
    return new Ext.data.JsonStore(Ext.apply({
        url: AVRMS.ROOT_CONTEXT + "/ssl/json/general/GetAircraftFees.aspx",
        idProperty: 'AircraftOid',
        baseParams: {
            OwnerOid: 0,
            SelectedAircraft: ''
        },
        fields: ['AircraftOid','NNumber', 'Make', 'Model', 'RegistrationFeeFormatted']
    }));
}   

var colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
        { id: 'AircraftOid', width: 100, sortable: true, locked: true, hidden: true, dataIndex: 'AircraftOid' },
        { header: "N-Number", width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true, dataIndex: 'NNumber' },
        { header: "Make", width: 250, sortable: true, hideable: false, dataIndex: 'Make' },
        { header: "Model", width: 250, sortable: true, hideable: false, dataIndex: 'Model' },
        { header: "Registration Fee", width: 150, sortable: true, hideable: false, dataIndex: 'RegistrationFeeFormatted' }
    ]); 


var registrationGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel(
    {
        store: aircraftFeesStore,
        cm: colModel,
        sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({ singleSelect: true }),
        viewConfig: {
            forceFit: true
        },
        width: 970,
        height: 150,
        split: true,
        region: 'north',
        frame: true,
        title: 'Selected Aircraft with Total'
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving

```
remoteSort:true
```

in your grid